# var a;(function(){let a=10;console.log(a);})();

Tags: ecmascript-6

```
var a;(function(){let a=10;console.log(a);})();
```

why it throws error as Uncaught Syntax Error: Identifier 'a' has already been declared  though scope is different for both    .

Comment: `var a;` and `let a;` are both declarations, hence `a` has been re declared in a scope where it already exists by `let a = 10;`

Comment: Can you provide more context? The code you provided parses runs just fine for me.

Comment: var declares a variable in a global scope ,whilst let declares a variable in a block scope, this means a has been declared already using var a; so remove the let and do it a=10;

Answer (score 1):

There is no syntax error there, see:

```js
var a;(function(){let a=10;console.log(a);})();
```

Most probably you were playing around in some sandbox or interpreter like the *NodeJS repl* or the *Chrome DevTools*, and you already declared `a` using `let a` in the global scope in one of your *previous experiments* in the same repl session.